# Oracle - How to use merge to update a column based on the values from other table and columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to update the values in closed_date column based on the values comparison from other columns and other table. I used Oracle merge into statement. But it gave me an error:

Error: ORA-00969: missing ON keyword

I am not sure what goes wrong. Do I miss anything? Below is my script:

```
MERGE INTO PR_DMN dmn
USING (select alg.PR_DMN_ID, alg.PR_ACTIVITY_ID, alg.ACTIVITY_TS from PR_ACTIVITY_LOG) alg
ON dmn.PR_DMN_ID = alg.PR_DMN_ID
-- update
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET dmn.CLOSED_DATE =
    (CASE 
        WHEN alg.PR_ACTIVITY_ID IN ('10009', '10010', '10011', '10013') THEN alg.ACTIVITY_TS
        WHEN alg.PR_ACTIVITY_ID = '10005' AND dmn.CONT_RESP_TS <= dmn.CONT_RESP_DUE_TS THEN dmn.CONT_RESP_TS 
        WHEN alg.PR_ACTIVITY_ID = '10008' AND dmn.CORR_RESP_TS <= dmn.CORR_RESP_DUE_TS THEN dmn.CORR_RESP_TS
        ELSE dmn.CLOSED_DATE 
    END)
```

Comment: It could easily be as simple as the fact you're using the `alg` alias inside your `using` sub-select, which you shouldn't be,

Comment: Thanks for your response. I noticed that the original error

Comment: Thanks for your response. I noticed that the original error `ORA-00969: missing ON keyword` was due to my missing the parenthesis after ON. It should be `ON (dmn.PR_DMN_ID = alg.PR_DMN_ID)`. But, after I fixed this problem, the new error states: `Error: ORA-00904: "ALG"."ACTIVITY_TS": invalid identifier`. My alg alias is sitting outside the using sub-select parenthesis. Did you mean I should put the alg alias inside the sub-select parenthesis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two errors, as you can see with a simple example. Firstly the `on` clause needs to be wrapped in parenthesis. Secondly, you can't reference the alias of the sub-select in the `using` clause within that sub-query.

If I set up a simple example using your table names as follows:

```
create table pr_dmn as
 select level as a, sysdate as b
   from dual
connect by level <= 10;

Table created.


create table PR_ACTIVITY_LOG as
 select level as a, sysdate as b
   from dual
connect by level <= 20;

Table created.
```

Then execute the correct query it should work:

```
merge into pr_dmn dmn
 using (select a, b from pr_activity_log) alg -- no alg. inside the sub-query
    on (dmn.a = alg.a) -- wrapped in parenthesis
  when matched then
update set dmn.b = alg.b
       ;

10 rows merged.
```

I always find [PSOUG](http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html) a good reference for things like this, though the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) has some good examples as well.

Comment: It works now after fixing these errors. Thank you very much, Ben:)

Comment: @Ben in Oracle using the merge will this same approach work with selecting from 2 tables ?